# Update view when scope change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Might be I am asking same question but I did not find the exact answer thats why I am putting this question again with proper code.

```
<table class="striped responsive-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
              <th data-field="id">
                    <p>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" ng-change="selectAll(curStatus)" ng-model="selectAllRecords"/>
                        <label for="selectAll">All</label>
                    </p>
              </th>
              <th>BASE TEMPLATE&</th>
              <th>PROCESS ELEMENT </th>
              <th>SCREEN NAME</th>
              <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="record in records | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter : searchItem track by $index">
            <td data-field="id">
                <p>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="{{record.id}}" ng-model="record.Selected"/>
                    <label for="{{record.id}}"></label>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td>{{record.baseTemplate}}</td>
            <td>{{record.processElement}}</td>
            <td>{{record.screenName}}</td>
            <td>
                <i class="material-icons tooltipped" data-position="top" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Edit Record">mode_edit</i>
                <i class="material-icons tooltipped" data-position="top" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Delete Record" style="color : #ee6e73">delete</i></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

this is my view

Controller is

```
$scope.sortType     = 'baseTemplate'; // set the default sort type
$scope.sortReverse  = false; 
$scope.selectAllRecords = false;
$scope.records = [
    {
        id : "record1",
        baseTemplate : "A",
        processElement : "PE1",
        screenName : "normal view",
    },{
        id : "record2",
        baseTemplate : "B",
        processElement : "PE2",
        screenName : "detail view"
    },{
        id : "record3",
        baseTemplate : "C",
        processElement : "PE3",
        screenName : "list view"
    }
];
$scope.addNew = function(){
    var id = $scope.records.length + 1;
    id = 'record' + id;
    $scope.records.push({
        id : id,
        baseTemplate : 'A',
        processElement : 'PE5',
        screenName : 'ACTION_BAR'
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.records));
};
```

I can see the changes when new record added in $scope.records. But its not getting reflected in my view.

any help would be a great support.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you put your code in a fiddle/plunkr ? I don't see anything wrong at first glance

Comment: Have you tried calling `$scope.apply()` at the end of the `addNew` function?

Comment: yes I am getting error $digest already in progress

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine to me. All I did was add a button that calls the `addNew` function. The new item is reflected in the view.

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.sortType = 'baseTemplate'; // set the default sort type
  $scope.sortReverse = false;
  $scope.selectAllRecords = false;
  $scope.records = [{
    id: "record1",
    baseTemplate: "A",
    processElement: "PE1",
    screenName: "normal view",
  }, {
    id: "record2",
    baseTemplate: "B",
    processElement: "PE2",
    screenName: "detail view"
  }, {
    id: "record3",
    baseTemplate: "C",
    processElement: "PE3",
    screenName: "list view"
  }];
  $scope.addNew = function() {
    var id = $scope.records.length + 1;
    id = 'record' + id;
    $scope.records.push({
      id: id,
      baseTemplate: 'A',
      processElement: 'PE5',
      screenName: 'ACTION_BAR'
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.records));
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <table class="striped responsive-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-field="id">
          <p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" ng-change="selectAll(curStatus)" ng-model="selectAllRecords" />
            <label for="selectAll">All</label>
          </p>
        </th>
        <th>BASE TEMPLATE&</th>
        <th>PROCESS ELEMENT</th>
        <th>SCREEN NAME</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="record in records | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter : searchItem track by $index">
        <td data-field="id">
          <p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="{{record.id}}" ng-model="record.Selected" />
            <label for="{{record.id}}"></label>
          </p>
        </td>
        <td>{{record.baseTemplate}}</td>
        <td>{{record.processElement}}</td>
        <td>{{record.screenName}}</td>
        <td>
          <i class="material-icons tooltipped" data-position="top" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Edit Record">mode_edit</i>
          <i class="material-icons tooltipped" data-position="top" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Delete Record" style="color : #ee6e73">delete</i>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button ng-click="addNew()">add new</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I already have button that is calling addNew(). Its adding the value as well in $scope.records I can see in console.. but I am not able to see this in my view.

Comment: if you run my code snippet, the new item is clearly added in the view. I don't see where the problem is?

Comment: Thanks for reply.. But the problem is not solved. I don't know why its not working. Adding button just below the table TAG it working absoultely fine. but I have a button above the table Tag that actually open a MODAL in which I am entering value then calling addNew() from MODAL then its not working

Comment: yes I am sure. Thats why its calling addNew method that is inside this controller only. Its also adding new records in $scope.records that I can see in my console. But not reflecting in my view.

Comment: well then we need an updated code sample that includes the modal

Comment: while debugging I got the issue but I am not to solve it.
actually when modal call addNew() method my controller getting initialize again. that is why its showing only previous records.

Comment: got the issue 

<a href="#" was the problem that was initialzing my controller again

Thanks for the support